# Python 2.7 function disappearing from module after import

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a python script that imports a function, and then imports a class from a module with the same name as the function. For example:

```
from antioch import parrot
from antioch.parrot import Spam
```

If I print `help(antioch)` after the first import statement, it shows `parrot()` listed under the FUNCTIONS, however if I print `help(antioch)` after the second import statement the FUNCTIONS list no longer includes the `parrot()` function.

This causes a problem later in my code when trying to call the function as I get a 'module object us not callable' error.

I realise that I could probably avoid this issue by renaming the parrot module to a different name to the function but this would involve editing quite a lot of code and seems like a workaround which shouldn't be necessary.

Is there a better way around this problem?

Comment: Why does `antioch` contain a function and a sub-module with the same name?! Assuming that's not a real module (which it totally should be), what are you actually using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply jon. I didn't write that part of the code, but was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require either to be edited (if this is possible). That's not the real module name. It's actually called ebaysdk the function and submodule are both called trading and the class is called Connection

Comment: Given [the definition of that function](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/ebaysdk/__init__.py#L50), why do you want it anyway? It's just a stub telling you the API has changed.

Comment: I'm running an older version of the ebaysdk software, so the function in the version that I am using is  def trading(*args, **kwargs):
    from ebaysdk.trading import Connection as Trading
    return Trading(*args, **kwargs)      Sorry - I don't know how to format the code in comments

Comment: ...that still doesn't explain why you want to access it. Just use the new-style import per the error message and your code will continue to work just fine. There's no reason that I can see to want access to both `antioch.trading`-the-function and `antioch.trading`-the-module, given that the former is just a convenience function to instantiate a class in the latter (it's backticks `\``, by the way).

Comment: Sorry if it's a dumb question but what do you mean by 'the new-style import per the error message'?

Comment: So if you use `from ebaysdk.trading import Connection as trading` in your code, you don't need that function at all; all it does it carry out that import and then instantiate and return the class, so just do that directly.

Comment: Thanks jon - you're a legend

Comment: No problem; this is just what the error message in the version I linked above tells you (and note that that's been the case for [18 months](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/commit/1cdbdb11ebc444c14418517d87ee37e64c46f675#diff-37e57b9aac5a791a64f8a16e359e37af), so it might be time to upgrade!)